# Construction Heuristic Phase slower since migration from 7.28 to 8.14

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

After migrating Optaplanner from version 7.28.0.FINAL to version 8.14.1.FINAL, the construction heuristic phase defined in the configuration as following :

```
  <constructionHeuristic>
    <constructionHeuristicType>STRONGEST_FIT</constructionHeuristicType>
  </constructionHeuristic>
```

is significantly slower than previous. When using V7.28 the solver is able to process with a score calculation speed of 6446/sec vs 102/sec (50 times slower) with the version 8.14

There were no changes in the constraints.drl, no change in the model except that the PlanningEntity movableEntitySelectionFilter field has been removed and replaced by a pinningFilter (that has the opposite logic implemented). Aside from that and the different migration upgrade, I cannot explain nor fix the drop of performance for the first phase. It is not critical, as it takes "only" 30 to 50 minutes to finish the CH phase (instead of 2-5 minutes before).

Is it possible that some performance shift have happened (that would require a different configuration) since the v7 for the CH phase? I've read the doc about scaling CH, but I don't think any is linked to this drop of performance.

EDIT, after profiling the task that execute the solver.solve(), here is a snapshot of the CPU time :

[image: visualvm_planner_profile_cpu_snapshot]

Comment: A couple of questions first, if I may:
Are both 7.28.0 and 8.14.1 running with the same Java version?
Is the performance after construction heuristic roughly equal for both OptaPlanner versions?
I would also try increase logging to figure out what's happening; please see https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2021/05/06/ThePathToOptaPlannerEnlightenmentStartsInTheLog.html.

Comment: Yes. Java version used is 14 - gradle build sourceCompatibility set to Java 11

Comment: For the second question, it's hard to measure but I'd say, yes there is no notable difference in performance of our localSearch phase. I've already set the logging of optaplanner to debug, that is how I figured out that the calculation speed is different.

Comment: Finally, there are more steps when using v7.28 than in v8.14.

Comment: This is cause for concerns, 50x times slower is unacceptable. We 'haven't seen this before in other upgrade cases. I presume they both use environmentMode REPRODICUBLE? What happens if you profile them with VisualVM?

Comment: It is in REPRODUCIBLE mode with same random seed (if this matters). I'll try profile them both and report back.

Comment: Hi @GeoffreyDeSmet, I had time to try profiling the app running with version 8.14 of Optaplanner. I edited my question to add the screenshot.

Comment: Thank you for reporting. This looks like a performance regression in Drools, used from OptaPlanner scoreDRL. We're working on a migration recipe to change from scoreDRL to constrainStreams, but there is no proof that that won't be affected either (it uses Drools under the hood by default).

Comment: For the record: we're not seeing this perf regression with any of our examples, any of our quickstarts, any of our customers and I am not aware of any other users reporting it. It must be something specific that drools messes up in your use case...

Comment: That crossed our mind that indeed Drools engine somehow is slower with the new version. We will most likely review our .drl rules in the hope that it positively affects performances. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet : Just to keep you updated, we managed to increase performances from 50 times slower to 10 times slower by re-writting drl rules and fine-tuning our solver configuration. It is still not ideal situation. We still believe that the Drools engine is probably the cause, without being able to prove it. Anyway, there is no silver bullet for our problem I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Do note that [scoreDRL is being deprecated](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2022/05/26/optaplanner-deprecates-score-drl.html) and there's a [guide to upgrade to CS](https://www.optaplanner.org/learn/drl-to-constraint-streams-migration.html).

Comment: We moved from scoreDRL to CS recently with improved preformances overall. Thanks for the notification.